# NPM error when trying to install React.js TODO-MVC Tutorial

Tags: node.js, npm, reactjs, todomvc

I am trying to install the react.js flux-todomvc tutorial from github [(link)](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc/), but after cloning the repo, running NPM install, and then running NPM start, NPM returns an error that looks like this:

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad-X220 ~/projects/www/flux-todomvc/flux $ npm install

> flux@2.0.3 prepublish /home/peter/projects/www/flux-todomvc/flux
> gulp publish

[15:36:43] Using gulpfile ~/projects/www/flux-todomvc/flux/Gulpfile.js
[15:36:43] Starting 'publish'...
[15:36:43] Starting 'clean'...
[15:36:43] Finished 'clean' after 14 ms
[15:36:43] Starting 'lib'...
[15:36:43] Finished 'lib' after 69 ms
[15:36:43] Starting 'browserify'...
[15:36:43] Finished 'browserify' after 85 ms
[15:36:43] Starting 'build'...
[15:36:43] Finished 'build' after 4.94 μs
[15:36:43] Finished 'publish' after 172 ms
peter@peter-ThinkPad-X220 ~/projects/www/flux-todomvc/flux $ npm start
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/peter/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/peter/projects/www/flux-todomvc/flux/npm-debug.log
```

Anyone have any idea how to trouble shoot this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out, and maybe it is pretty simple mistake, but perhaps this will help someone else who found the documentation unclear (as I did).

When running the npm commands (npm install and npm start) you need to be in the root folder of the example project, not the root folder of the github repo.

In other words,  to install and run the todoMVC example project you should be in the following directory:

```
flux/examples/flux-todomvc
```

**NOT** in this directory:

```
flux/
```